# How do scientists determine the nature of ions passing through a channel/carrier/pump?

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, electrophysiology, methods

The NCE (Sodium Calcium Exchanger) transports 3 Na+ inside the cell for 1 Ca2+ outside.
How did we figure this out, and other mechanisms of this sort?
If it were a protein, we could tag it with GFP. But they're ions.
Looking at potentials isnt very informative either I guess; both K+ and Na+ have the same charge.
What is done, experimentally?